# Trying to fix subview flipping and now subview buttons no longer work?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, button, subview

I have a view which includes two subviews.  I had it working so that only one subview was shown at a time and each subview had a button and when the button was clicked the subview would flip over and the next subview would appear. The problem was that it appeared as though the entire view was flipping. After reading on this site about how to solve the problem I attempted to add the subviews to a container and flip that instead. However now, although my first subview is showing up when I press the button it no longer flip. It doesn't do anything. I put a log statement in the method which flips the subviews, as well as a breakpoint and as far as I can tell it no longer gets called. I'm very new to xcode and objective c and delegates and I have no idea how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

I have included the relevant code here:
The header for the ViewController

```
@interface ExerciseViewController : UIViewController<ExerciseSubViewDelegate>

//stuff for subviews
@property (nonatomic, strong) ExerciseSubViewImage *subViewImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ExerciseSubViewText *subViewText;
@property UIView *panel;

@end
```

This is the code for the ViewController:

```
@interface ExerciseViewController ()

@end

@implementation ExerciseViewController

@synthesize subViewImage, subViewText;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.subViewImage.delegate = self;

    _panel = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.bounds.size.width,  self.view.bounds.size.height/2)];
    _panel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:_panel];
   [_panel addSubview:subViewImage];
}
-(ExerciseSubViewImage *)subViewImage
{
   if (!subViewImage)
   {

       CGRect subViewImageFrame = CGRectMake(0,0, _panel.bounds.size.width, _panel.bounds.size.height);
       self.subViewImage = [[ExerciseSubViewImage alloc] initWithFrame:subViewImageFrame];

       [_panel addSubview:subViewImage];

   }
    return subViewImage;
}
-(ExerciseSubViewText *)subViewText
{
    if (!subViewText)
    {

        CGRect subViewTextFrame = CGRectMake(0,0, _panel.bounds.size.width, _panel.bounds.size.height);
        self.subViewText = [[ExerciseSubViewText alloc] initWithFrame:subViewTextFrame];

        self.subViewText.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [_panel addSubview:subViewText];
    }
    return subViewText;
}

-(void)exerciseSubViewImagePressed
{

    [UIView transitionWithView:_panel
                      duration:0.2
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    animations:^{
                         [subViewImage removeFromSuperview];
                        [_panel addSubview:subViewText];
                    }
                      completion: nil];
//This is how I did it before I added the container
    /*[UIView transitionFromView:subViewImage
                        toView:subViewText
                      duration:0.2
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    completion:nil];
    self.subViewText.delegate = self;*/
    NSLog(@"Ipushedtheimage");
}
-(void)exerciseSubViewTextPressed
{//I haven't updated this yet
   [UIView transitionFromView:subViewText
                        toView:subViewImage
                      duration:0.2
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    completion:nil];
    self.subViewImage.delegate = self;



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    subViewImage = nil;

    subViewText = nil;

}

@end
```

This is the code for the delegate
    #import

```
@protocol ExerciseSubViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) exerciseSubViewImagePressed;
-(void) exerciseSubViewTextPressed;
```

@end
I am also added the code for the first subview:
    #import 
    #import "ExerciseSubViewDelegate.h"

```
@interface ExerciseSubViewImage : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *button;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ExerciseSubViewDelegate>delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *exerciseImageView;


@end


#import "ExerciseSubViewImage.h"
#import "UIImage+animatedGIF.h"

@implementation ExerciseSubViewImage

@synthesize button;
@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        //Initialization code
        self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(50,200,100,35);
        self.button.frame = buttonFrame;
        [self.button setTitle:@"Image"forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.button addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(buttonTouched)
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:self.button];

        _exerciseImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,20,160,158)]; 

        NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"AppleLogo" withExtension:@"gif"];
        _exerciseImageView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:url];
                             [self addSubview:self.exerciseImageView];


    }
    return self;
}
-(void)buttonTouched
{
    NSLog(@"imagebuttonpressed");
    [self.delegate exerciseSubViewImagePressed];
}
```

Again, any help would be appreciate. I know I'm probably just not understanding something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. This took me all weekend but I finally figured it out on my own. I thought I would shere the answer here in case anyone else ever has a similar problem. After trying several other approaches I finally went back to the approach I used here and started inserting a whole bunch of NSLogs to determine the order that every thing was executing in. What I finally ended up doing was changing this: (all in the top ViewController)

```
  self.subViewImage.delegate = self;

    _panel = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.bounds.size.width,    self.view.bounds.size.height/2)];
    _panel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:_panel];
   [_panel addSubview:subViewImage];
```

to this:

```
    //create panel
    _panel = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.bounds.size.width, s   self.view.bounds.size.height/2)];
    _panel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:_panel];
    [_panel addSubview:subViewImage];

    //Set the subview delegates
    self.subViewImage.delegate = self;
    self.subViewText.delegate = self;
```